# How to generate random directed connected graph?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, random

How to generate random directed connected graph?

I need to create graph which will pass:

```
ConnectedGraphQ[^]
```

Comment: You've seen `RandomGraph[]`? It has a `DirectedEdges` option...

Comment: How many vertices and edges do you need? If the number of edges is sufficiently large compared to the number of vertices, then it's highly likely a random graph (with uniform distribution) will be connected anyway, so you can just generate random (possibly disconnected) graphs with `RandomGraph` until you obtain a connected one.

Comment: Alternatively to @whuber's approach, you could place random connections between the connected components. Might be useful, if you want a relatively sparse graph.

Comment: @Mark Wouldn't that destroy the intended distribution? Also, if the numbers of edges are to be prescribed in advance, that would add too many edges.

Comment: @whuber I didn't see anything in the question about a particular distribution.

Comment: @Mark "Random" does not mean arbitrary: it implies that a distribution is specified. See the [MMA help page for `RandomGraph`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RandomGraph.html) to get a sense of its emphasis on allowing the user to specify how many vertices, how many edges, *and the distribution* of the edge frequencies. When you don't pay any attention to the distribution, you open yourself up to [silly output](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/424).

Comment: @whuber Having published several papers on the growth of trees in random constructions, I'm well aware of the nature of random graphs, thank you. I'm simply suggesting the basis of a strategy for dealing with sparse graphs. If my comment (not answer) seems to lack detail, perhaps that's because the question lacks detail.

Comment: Usually they cut down trees before construction. They must do things differently in Asheville...

Comment: @DanielLichtblau The US Forest service was born in Asheville; we've cut down far too many trees!

Comment: @whuber Now that this question has become popular, I added an answer which should lead to interesting graphs.  I guess that yet another approach would be to grab the largest connected component of a randomly generated graph.  I still have no clue what the OP was really after, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
ConnectComponents[{a_, b_}] := 
  DirectedEdge[RandomChoice[a], RandomChoice[b]];
ConnectedGraph[n_, m_, o___] := 
  Module[{vertices = n, edges = m, options = o},
   rg = RandomGraph[{vertices, edges}, DirectedEdges -> True];
   cc = ConnectedComponents[rg];
   edges = 
    If[Length@cc != 1, 
     ConnectComponents /@ Partition[cc, 2, 1, 1], {}];
   Graph[DeleteDuplicates[ edges~Join~EdgeList[rg]], 
    Sequence@options]
   ];
```

Answer (score 10):

A *random geometric graph* is generated by choosing some points in the plane and then connecting two vertices if they are within a certain distance.  If the distance is chosen appropriately, the graph will be connected.  Here's an implementation that uses a bisection method to determine the smallest appropriate distance.

```
SeedRandom[3];
pts = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {50, 2}];
vertices = v /@ pts;
len = Length[pts];
a = 0.0; b = 1.5;
While[a < b,
  c = a + 0.5 (b - a);
  clusters = Table[
    Nearest[pts[[i ;; len]], pts[[i]], {len, c}],
    {i, 1, len - 1}];
  toEdges[pp : {{_Real, _Real} ..}] := 
   UndirectedEdge[v[First[pp]], v[#]] & /@ Rest[pp];
  edges = Flatten[toEdges /@ clusters];
  g = Graph[vertices, edges];
  If[! ConnectedGraphQ[g], a = c, b = c]
  ];
clusters = Table[
   Nearest[pts[[i ;; len]], pts[[i]], {len, b}],
   {i, 1, len - 1}];
edges = Flatten[toEdges /@ clusters];
g = Graph[vertices, DirectedEdge @@@ edges,
  VertexShapeFunction -> ({Disk[#, 0.007]} &),
  EdgeStyle -> Opacity[0.3],
  VertexCoordinates -> pts]
```

[image]

Not terribly efficient, of course.  1000 vertices took about 30 sec.

[image]

Here's a geometric random graph with a highlighted spanning tree which is minimal with respect to total edge length, yielding an interesting dendritic structure.

[image]

Comment: +1 Or, to push this kind of idea even further, generate points uniformly at random within a region and compute their Euclidean minimum spanning tree.  With that as a backdrop you could then add more edges according to any distribution you want.

Comment: @whuber See edit.  I did this quite some time ago and, unfortunately, the technique is not wholly within mathematica.  It relies on a weighted spanning tree algorithm which, as far as I know, is not implemented in Mathematica.  There is a `SpanningTree` command in the `SparseArray` context, but I'm not clear on how it works.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a *rejection method*:

```
With[{v = 8 (* vertices *), e = 14 (* edges *)}, 
     NestWhile[RandomGraph[{v, e}, DirectedEdges -> True] &, 
               Graph[{1 \[UndirectedEdge] 1, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 2}], 
               Composition[Not, ConnectedGraphQ]]]
```

[image: random directed connected graph]

Answer (score 3):

With even small (**reasonably**) edge probabilities this function will generate in a **reasonably** short time  random directed connected graph:

```
gr[n_, p_] := Module[{
           g = RandomGraph[BernoulliGraphDistribution[n, p], DirectedEdges -> True]}, 
            While[Not[ConnectedGraphQ[g]], 
             g = RandomGraph[BernoulliGraphDistribution[n, p], DirectedEdges -> True]]; g]
```

Use:

```
gr[#, .2] & /@ Range[7, 22]
```

[image]

Check:

```
ConnectedGraphQ /@ %
```

> {True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True}